# What are segr6 and segr7 under x86 ISA

Tags: x86

When I tried to use ndisasm to disassemble 8CF0 - 8CFF, I found some unfamliliar registers, segr6 and segr7.
After doing some googles, I didn't find anything useful.
What is segr6 and segr7?

`8CF0 mov ax,segr6
8CF1 mov cx,segr6
8CF2 mov dx,segr6
8CF3 mov bx,segr6
8CF4 mov sp,segr6
8CF5 mov bp,segr6
8CF6 mov si,segr6
8CF7 mov di,segr6
8CF8 mov ax,segr7
8CF9 mov cx,segr7
8CFA mov dx,segr7
8CFB mov bx,segr7
8CFC mov sp,segr7
8CFD mov bp,segr7
8CFE mov si,segr7
8CFF mov di,segr7`

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, the bytes you're disassembling are probably not intended to be code.  i.e. they're used as data, not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't exist. These instructions are `mov reg, sreg` where `sreg` is a segment register, but the number of the segment register they encode is out of range. There are only 6 segment registers, 0 through 5. 6 and 7 are reserved.